# Need some help regarding Redux Toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-redux, redux-toolkit

The thunk appears as follows:

```js
export const registerUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/register",
  async (userData) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(REGISTER_URL, userData);
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      // console.log(error.response.data) the output is provided below
      throw error.response.data;
    }
  }
);
```

Output:

```json
{
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": [
    "email should not be empty",
    "email must be an email"
  ],
  "statusCode": 400
}
```

Given this output format, how should I structure the state.error update within the reducer's .addMatcher()?

```js
.addMatcher(
  (action) => action.type.endsWith("/rejected"),
  (state, action) => {
    state.loading = false;
    state.error = ?; // What's the appropriate way to structure the error messages?
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably actually ***return*** a rejected Promise with the error instead of just rethrowing it. See [Handling Thunk Errors](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#handling-thunk-errors) for more details.

Example:

```js
export const registerUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/register",
  async (userData, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(REGISTER_URL, userData);
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      // console.log(error.response.data) the output is provided below
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
    }
  }
);
```

From here it will just be in the `registerUser.rejected` action's `payload`.

```js
.addMatcher(
  (action) => action.type.endsWith("/rejected"),
  (state, action) => {
    state.loading = false;
    state.error = action.payload; // or pick out what you need from payload
  }
)
```